# modify complete.ly options based on textbox value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, complete.ly

I want to change the autocomplete options of a complete.ly object based on the selection made in another dropdown list.

I call the `updateAuto` function through JQuery by doing `$("#ddlToWatch").change(updateAuto)`.

The `updateAuto` function definition is as follows :

```
function updateAuto() {

var optionsDD;
if ($("#ddlToWatch").val() == "bla") {
    optionsDD = [
     'blabla',
     'blabla2'
    ];
};

$("#mycompletelybox").options = optionsDD;

};
```

It seems like you can't access directly the `options` using `JQuery` for `complete.ly` objects. What is the recommended way to access those if that is indeed the issue ?

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up initializing the textbox with a global variable

```
var mybox;
$(function() {
    mybox = completely($("#mycompletelybox"), {color:'black'});
}
```

and using that variable in my code above.
So, instead of

```
$("#mycompletelybox").options = optionsDD;
```

use

```
mybox.options = optionsDD;
```